# Custom ftp authentication not called for every login

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, logging, ftp

I have added File.appendtext logger in ftp authentication DLL.but I observed that it doesnot log for every ftp loggin.

At first login it writes in log-file but next login it doesn't write in log-file.if I enter wrong password next time then it writes in log-file.

Is there session maintained for successful login?
what is the best approach for audit logger inside ftp DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Execute following command to disable caching of FTP server.

**Appcmd.exe set config -section:system.ftpServer/caching/credentialsCache.enabled:"False" /commit:apphost**

This command will make entry in applicationHost file which is located at “C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\ applicationHost”